# PDO: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Tags: php, mysql, select, pdo

I can't find the error in my code. I'm trying to fetch the results in an array. The SQL query is correct, I tried it in my PHPMYADMIN. `$team` is an interger.

What did I do wrong? I am very new to PDO.

EDIT: paramater dumps

```
SQL: [207] select a.start, a.end, a.type_FK, a.absences_ID, employee_FK, e.surname, e.name, e.cts from employee e JOIN absences a ON e.employee_ID=a.employee_FK WHERE approved = 0 and team_FK = :team order by start ASC Params: 1 Key: Name: [5] :team paramno=-1 name=[5] ":team" is_param=1 param_type=2


$sql = "select a.start, a.end, a.type_FK, a.absences_ID, employee_FK, e.surname, e.name, e.cts from employee e JOIN absences a ON e.employee_ID=a.employee_FK WHERE approved = 0 and team_FK = :team order by start ASC";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array(':team' => $team));
    $unapproved = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php --- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: I already use $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

Answer (score 0):

You are not telling mysql what is the table of "employee_FK" .. So the correct query will be . You were adding extra "e" near "employee e JOIN"

```
$sql = "select a.start, a.end, a.type_FK, a.absences_ID, a.employee_FK, e.surname, e.name, e.cts from employee JOIN absences a ON e.employee_ID=a.employee_FK WHERE approved = 0 and team_FK = :team order by start ASC";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array(':team' => $team));
    $unapproved = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Comment: I am: its a for absences

Comment: You are writing employee_FK instead of a.employee_FK .. That's the problem i think .. Did you tried fixing it ?

Comment: I'm sure the query is correct, it worked when I used it with MySQLi and it still displays most of the data (until the the name appears)

Comment: I added the paramater dumps